# Angular : Transfer a single list item from array list using service to another service?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular-services

### Transfer single item from a list item to cart list.

I am developing an **Angular** web app and want that when I click a button the single item of an array gets transferred from one **service** to another service and is also transferred on another component. I have successfully implemented it with a transfer of whole array but I am facing problem with a single item.Please help.

---

What I want is that when I click on `Add to cart` button the list item which is clicked only gets transferred and not the array of list items.

---

**buyGame.html file**

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <a class="list-group-item clearfix" style="background-color:rgb(3, 0, 48)" *ngFor="let buying of buy">
        <div class="pull-left" style="max-width:330px">
            <h5 style="color:white">{{buying.names}}</h5>
            <p style="color:white">{{buying.desc}}</p>
            <button class="btn btn-danger ; pull-left" (click)= "onAddToCart()">Add To Cart</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="pull-right">
                <img [src]="buying.getImg" alt="image not loaded" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:100px">
            </span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**buygame.service.ts file :**

```
import { gameBuy } from "./buygame.model";
import { Injectable,EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { cartService } from "./cart.service";

@Injectable()
export class gameService{

    private gameServ: gameBuy[] = [
        new gameBuy('batman','Batmobile and enhancements to signature features',"https://www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/batmans-625x352.jpg"),
        new gameBuy('GTA 5',
        "PlayStation 3 or Xbox 360 will be able to transfer their current Grand Theft Auto Online characters and progression to their choice of PlayStation 4 Xbox One or PC",
        "http://onlysp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/maxresdefault.jpg")
    ];

    constructor(private cartSer: cartService){}

    getBuyingList(){
        return this.gameServ.slice();
    }

    addItemToCart(game:gameBuy[]){
        this.cartSer.addItem(game);
    }
}
```

**buyGame.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { gameBuy } from '../shared/buygame.model';
import { gameService } from '../shared/buygame.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-buy-game',
  templateUrl: './buy-game.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./buy-game.component.css'],
})
export class BuyGameComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() buy:gameBuy[];

  constructor(private service: gameService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buy = this.service.getBuyingList();
  }

  onAddToCart(){
 this.service.addItemToCart(this.buy);
  }
}
```

**cart.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { cartModel } from '../shared/cart.model';
import { cartService } from '../shared/cart.service';
import { gameBuy } from '../shared/buygame.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.component.css'],
})
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {

   cart:gameBuy[];

  constructor(private service: cartService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cart = this.service.getCartItem();
  }

}
```

**cart.service.ts:**

```
import { cartModel } from "./cart.model";
import { EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { gameBuy } from "./buygame.model";

export class cartService{

    cartChanged = new EventEmitter<gameBuy[]>();
    private cart: gameBuy[] = [
        new gameBuy('Batman','Batman is a cool game','https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91lu5KHSm3L._SY445_.jpg'),
        new gameBuy('Gta 5','online game of GTA','https://www.rockstargames.com/V/img/global/order/mobile-cover.jpg')
    ];

    getCartItem(){
        return this.cart.slice();
    }

    addItem(cart:gameBuy[]){
        this.cart.push(...cart);
        this.cartChanged.emit(this.cart.slice());
    }
}
```

**cart.model.ts:**

```
export class cartModel{
    constructor(public cartName: string,public cartDesc: string,public cartImage:string){}
}
```

**buygame.model.ts:**

```
export class gameBuy{
    constructor(public names:string, public desc:string, public getImg:string){}
}
```

Comment: you can handle this complex cases using `ngrx/store`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify exact item you want to be added to the cart in the temlate:

```
(click)= "onAddToCart(buying)"
```

And then pass it right to your service as `onAddToCart` method parameter:

```
onAddToCart(buying: gameBuy){
  this.service.addItemToCart(buying);
}
```

Also, your `buygame` service method should accept a single item, not a list:

```
addItemToCart(game: gameBuy){
    this.cartSer.addItem(game);
}
```

Atl last, `cart` service should be updated too (just to push a single item)

```
 addItem(cart:gameBuy){
    this.cart.push(cart);
    this.cartChanged.emit([...this.cart]); // slice() is ok too if you need a copy
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help sir, But i am getting error when i try to remove array from `addItemToCart()`, the error is `Argument of type gameBuy is not assignable to parameter of type gameBuy[ ]`, Please help

Comment: @RohitB You need to make a change to your `addItemToCart` service 
 method: `addItemToCart(game: gameBuy)`

Comment: Yes sir, i changed this in buyGame service but the error is still showing.

Comment: @RohitB Sorry, I've missed `cart` service, it certainly should be updated too. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the index in your call (click)= "onAddToCart(index)" and get it from your array.

OR provide the single object in (click)= "onAddToCart(buying)"

then receive it on TS